# Windows C++ multibyte / unicode

Tags: c++, unicode

In Windows C++ multibyte / unicode considerations, I notice that _tcslen() and lstrlen() both provide a string's length correctly regardless of whether you're compiling to multibyte or unicode.

_tcslen() is defined in TCHAR.H based on the def _UNICODE and lstrlen() is defined in WINBASE.H based on the def UNICODE.

Did someone just re-invent the wheel at some point or is there a reason for this apparent duplication?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2654087/Whats-the-differences-between-lstrlen-and-_tcslen.aspx

Comment: No, those are *macros* that map to either ANSI (char)or multibyte (wchar) functions and types. There's no duplication and as for `re-invent` those macros were there since the early 90s to allow people to compile the same code for ANSI or Unicode. Remember, OSs didn't use Unicode before Windows NT. C++ only added Unicode in 2011 with the `char16_t`, `char32_t`,`std::u16string` and `std::u32string` types.

Comment: In any case, you *shouldn't* mix up C functions and types like `lstrlen` or` _tcslen` in C++. You should use the language's types and algorithms. Use [std::string.length()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) or [u16string.length()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/u16string/). You should use `auto` for type inference. Use and pass references and smart pointers with [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers that can easily leak. Iterators instead of pointer arithmetic

Comment: One set of functions (macros) is part of the language runtime, the other set is part of the operating system. Neither is useful if you know beforehand what kind of character set your program is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lstrlen` and other `lstrxxx` functions are Windows APIs. They have ANSI and Unicode versions `lstrlenA` and `lstrenW`. They had some advantages over `strlen` back in the days of Windows 3.1. They don't have any advantages now. If you write your code with these functions it will not be compatible with any standard in C, it will only compile in Windows.

`_tstrlen` is a macro for either ANSI `strlen` or Unicode `wcslen` which are standard C. This was useful in the 1990s and early 2000s because you could write one set of code which could be compiled in ANSI for Windows 95, and Unicode for Windows NT. It's also useful because Microsoft can write one set of documentation for both ANSI and Unicode.

Otherwise these `_tstrxxx` string macros and `TCHAR` etc. are no longer useful. There is no point to go through all this pain to write code which is compatible for Windows 95. You can just use "wide c-string" `wcsxxx` functions which are standard C.

But then, the *nix operating systems use UTF-8 and `strxxx` functions. As opposed to Windows which uses UTF-16 and `wcsxxx`. I suppose you could use the `_tstrxxx` macros to write code which is Unicode compatible in both *nix and Windows. Other programmers will be confused by your `_tstrxxx` macros but at least the code has a better chance to compile!

Comment: The reason I'm using these dual use macros is because I'm adding a new DLL to a Windows c++ project containing ~ 1000 DLLs all built to multibyte. My DLL may be reused in the future in a Unicode project.